# How to set background-size with jQuery with both height and width

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set div's background-size with jQuery (it should depend on other elements). The problem is that while I can set it with one value, like this:

```
contentHeight = $('#content').outerHeight(true);
$('#background').css('background-size', contentHeight);
```

It doesn't do anything if I do it like this:

```
contentHeight = $('#content').outerHeight(true);
$('#background').css('background-size', 'auto ' + contentHeight + 'px !important');
```

I have a feeling that I made a silly mistake, but I fail to see it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do like this:

```
contentHeight = $('#content').outerHeight(true);
$('#background').css('background-size', "auto " + contentHeight + "px", "important");
```

Or

```
contentHeight = $('#content').outerHeight(true);
$('#background').css({'background-size': "auto " + contentHeight + "px !important"});
```

Comment: Just noticed that the second option doesn't work though... doesn't do anything.

Comment: try backgroundSize instead of 'background-size'

Answer (score 1):

See this :-

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d22fP/)

```
var size = "auto " + contentHeight + "px !important";
alert(size);
$('#background').css('background-size', size);
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer! Unfortunately I can't rate up answers yet due to my low reputation...

Comment: 1 Nice comment is enough :-) ...!!